# Tcl: Directory deletion - how to ignore files that cannot be deleted

Tags: directory, tcl

Deletion of a directory created problems if files are in use

```
(SETUP) 13 % file delete -force -- $env(TMP)
error deleting "../Temp\abcd": permission denied
```

Is there an option that allows ignoring files/dirs that show deletion violation?
I don't mind if some files / dirs are not deleted as long as I am cleaning up bulk of temp files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `file delete` in a `catch` statement:

```
catch { file delete -force -- $env(TMP) }
```

I hope you never run this as root.  Deleting your /tmp directory would be a bad thing.

References: [catch](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/catch.htm)

Comment: This will stop at the first failure it encounters - i want the code to ignore failures (similar to skip button on "permission denied / cannot delete" dialog) and move ahead deleting all directories and contained files - skipping any subsequent errors.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of your other question.